# Find all occurrences of a byte sequence in a binary file

Tags: c++, std

Please help me understand how to use `std::search` to get all occurrences of {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01} in a binary file.

The Code below finds the first occurrence:

```cpp
std::string NAL = "\x00\x00\x00\x01";
std::ifstream source("somedata.dat", std::ios::binary);
std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> begin(source), end, currNAL;
currNAL = std::search(begin, end, NAL.begin(), NAL.end());
```

I do not understand how to use `std::search` in a while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Since std::search() returns and iterator to the first occurrence, you can just use that first occurance as your (non-inclusive) starting point to search again.

```
while(currNAL != source.end()){
    currNAL = std::search(++currNAL, end, NAL.begin(), NAL.end());
    //Increment some counter here?
}
```

I should note this is untested code and I'm not meaning this to be an exact solution for your exact problem, just demonstrating the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example showing how search can be used to find all the instances using a `vector`. The ideas still apply to your case, you're just using `istream_iterator` instead of `vector` iterators.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::vector<unsigned char> vec(500);

  for(int i=0; i < 500; i++)
    vec[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>(i % 100);

  std::vector<unsigned char> pattern { 'A', 'B' };

  auto start = vec.begin();  // start searching a beginning
  while ( (start = std::search(start, vec.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end())) != vec.end()) {
    std::cout << "Found at index: " << std::distance(vec.begin(), start) << std::endl;
    start++;     // Search after this match on next iteration
  }
  return 0;
}
```